Subnetting Question Doubt , Check Body
A college was assigned a single block starting with 103.114.1.0/24,
create 3 subnets for 3 departments
a. 150 addresses for computer science department
b. 80 addresses for electrical engineering department
c. 20 addresses for administrative department
How does one create a subnet in this case.
For case a the closest 2^n for 150 is 256 i.e. it will occupy the whole block itself.
my approach was to just divide the ip addresses into ranges without subnetting, but that does not feel right.
(Edited)

This two-part answer has a section that explicitly deals with something like that.

Also, all "education, certification, or homework questions" are explicitly off-topic here. There are many that are wrong or poorly written.

@RonMaupin This was a question that came up on my exam, I couldn't Solve it.
